# Autofocus back to old box after modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, autofocus

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I can't find anything on it.

I am very new to Javascript and am still trying to understand event listeners and how code runs.

Aside from that, I have a bootstrap modal window that pops up when a number is put in an input box and posted.

There is an autofocus on that input box before the modal pops up.

I found help here on how to put the autofocus on a button on the modal window, and it works perfectly fine, as so:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

My problem is when that modal window is closed, I can't get the autofocus back to the input box.

I have tried various versions, these two being my main ideas:

```
$("#no").click(function() {
  $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});

$("#no").click(function() {
  $("staffID").focus();
});
```

Where staffID is the id of the input box.

But it doesn't put the focus back on the input box. The #no id is an id on the modal, so if you press no, you want the original site back with focus on the input.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Was asked for the HTML as well, here it is (ignore the Icelandic words):

```
<!--CLOCKIN INPUT FORM-->
<form id="staffIdForm" method="post" action="" class="clockin-form">
      <input id="staffID" type="text" name="starfsmannanumer" class="clockin-box" placeholder="Starfsmannanúmer" autofocus/>
      <button id="clockIn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Stimpla</button>
</form>

<!-- WELCOME MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="welcome-modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="welcomeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="welcomeModalLabel">
                          Góðan daginn <span id="nafn"></span>
                      </h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>Innstimplun skráð <span id="time"></span> þann <span id="date"></span></p>
                     <p>Viltu skrá þig í hádegismat?</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button id="no" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" autofocus>Nei</button>
                     <button id="yes" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Já</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The following javascript needed to run the problem:

```
$("#clockIn").off('click').on('click', function () {
     $("#staffIdForm").submit();
});


$(function getEmployee() {
$("#staffIdForm").on('submit', function(e) {

    var staffId = (document.getElementById("staffID").value);
    console.log(staffId);
    $.post("Attendance/Home/ClockIn", { starfsmannanumer: staffId }, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#nafn").text(data.name);
        $("#clock-out-nafn").text(data.name);


        $(function () {
            //Display time in message
            var dt = new Date();
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
            document.getElementById("clock-out-time").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');

            //Date message with Icelandic names
            var monthNames = [
                "jan&#250;ar", "febr&#250;ar", "mars", "apr&#237;l", "ma&#237;", "j&#250;n&#237;",
                "j&#250;l&#237;", "&#225;g&#250;st", "september", "okt&#243;ber", "n&#243;vember", "desember"]
            var day = dt.getDate();
            var monthIndex = dt.getMonth();
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = day + ". " + monthNames[monthIndex];;
            document.getElementById("clock-out-date").innerHTML = day + ". " + monthNames[monthIndex];;


            //Either check in or out message or error
            if (data.userId == "-1") {
                $("#invalid-staff-id").fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    $("#invalid-staff-id").delay(2000).fadeOut();
                });
            }
            else if (data.timeIn != null && data.timeOut == null) {
                $("#welcome-modal").stop(true).modal('show');
            }
            else if (data.timeIn != null && data.timeOut != null) {
                $("#clock-out-message").fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $("#clock-out-message").delay(5000).fadeOut();
                    //TODO: L�ta �tstimplunarskilabo� hverfa ef �tt er � takka
                    //TODO: Autofocus � 'Nei' takkann
                });
            }
        })
        document.getElementById("staffID").value = "";
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
});

$('#welcome-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});

$('#welcome-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("staffID").focus();
});
```

I think that is all that is needed.

Comment: Can we see your HTML as well? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: I also notice that `staffID` isn't a proper [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Perhaps it should be `#staffID`.

Comment: Just added HTML and JavaScript that as the problem.

Comment: Oh gosh, I forgot to put it, have changed it so many times. Thanks for noticing, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind input focus on modal close. Working solution will be:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus();
});
```

Also take a note, that here:

```
$("#no").click(function() {
  $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

`this` - is the element you clicked on - seems to be not correct try to find some other DOM element inside of it

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sounds logical. Somehow it doesn't do the trick for me. I might be doing the whole JavaScript wrong though...

Comment: MY BAD. Like @showdev noted here above, I forgot the # when refering to the id. This solved my problem. Thank you very much!